# Message to another computer via Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Is it possible to message another computers on a network via Excel VBA?
Example: If I save a shared Excel file on a network, it will send a message to other shared users whether they are using that shared file or not.

Answer (score 1):

To send a message to other computers on the network (DOS window):

1.

**msg** /Server:serverName * /Time:5 "Message text..."

**msg** /Server:192.168.1.1 "Message text..."

[Details](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/cc771903.aspx) (from Microsoft):

```
msg
  {UserName|SessionName|SessionID|@FileName|*}
  [/server:ServerName]
  [/time:Seconds]
  [/v]
  [/w]
  [Message]
```

2.

**net send** 192.168.0.1 "Message text..."

[Details](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/net_send.mspx?mfr=true):

```
net send {name | * | /domain[:name] | /users} message
```

.

**From VBA** you can use something like this:

```
Dim result As Long

result = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run("msg /Server:192.168.1.1 'Message text...'")
```

Or this:

```
Shell("msg /Server:192.168.1.1 'Message text...'", vbNormalFocus)
```

.

PS. A shared file cannot send a message if it's inactive, but you can implement a VBA procedure that will automatically send a message to a list of named computers (or IP addresses) when someone opens the file (Workbook_Open() event of ThisWorkbook module) or when they access / edit certain cells on a sheet

Answer (score 0):

The Excel VBA they may be running is running on their computers, you may not open the same files unless they are shared (even if shared I don't know how the variables stored in VBE are behaving).
Shared spreadsheets can be used to store variables, e.g. timestamps and userIDs (by the above description: in cells). You can have macros saved in them **before** sharing them that would check the variables and notify if something relevant ha happened.
Alternatively you can spam them all with emails from Excel to Outlook VBA.